# Is it okay to start a sentence with an appositive?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, appositives

I know you can use them in the middle of a sentence, but is it okay to start sentences with them?

Example: A kind of a duck, the Mallard, can be found all throughout the world.

Comment: It is, but your sentence doesn't begin with one. Paired commas often surround "removable" appositives, so "the Mallard" would presumably be the appositive. To make "a kind of duck" the appositive, the commas should surround it (with the comma at the beginning of the sentence being omitted, of course).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan : What are you saying? I agree that *the Mallard* is an appositive in the above sentence. How do you propose to start a sentence with an appositive?

Comment: @TinfoilHat "A kind of a duck, the Mallard can be found all throughout the world." "The Mallard" is now clearly the subject.

Comment: That's not an example of apposition, but supplementation: 'the mallard' could not be removed without changing the essential meaning of the sentence. For it to be apposition, there'd have to be a definite NP, like '_This_ kind of duck, the Mallard, can be found all throughout the world'.

Comment: @DW256 : What would your grammar call *the Mallard* in *A certain kind of duck [, the Mallard,] can be found all throughout the world*? (Insert *certain* — then *the Mallard* **can** be removed.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan : I see where you're coming from now.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, "the mallard" is subject. "A kind of duck" is a supplementary ascriptive NP preceding its 'anchor'.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, you can insert appositives virtually anywhere in a sentence: beginning, middle, or end.

- My best friend, Weird Al Yankovic, had what I would call an "interesting" upbringing.
- There have been many alleged sightings of "Nessie," the Loch Ness Monster, but very few of them are convincing, at least to scientists.
- When I am in a real quandary, and I'm not sure what to do, I go to the smartest person I know, my dad.

Comment: Only the last of the three examples given here is an example of apposition. The first is supplementation as 'My best friend' could not be removed without changing the essential meaning of the statement. The second doesn't seem to have anything close to apposition in it as it stands, but could be made into an example of apposition by removing 'also known as'.

Comment: Only specifying NPs can be appositives."A real weirdo" is ascriptive, not specifying, and hence it doesn't qualify. I agree with DW256 about your second and third examples.

Comment: @DW256: Thanks for the suggestions. I've revised my answer accordingly. Don

Comment: @Billj: Thanks for the suggestions. I've revised my answer accordingly. Don

Comment: ... These are of course the CGEL usages of 'appositive'. I've not found an article comparing/contrasting different usages (claiming one is 'correct' almost certainly chooses _one_ earlier stipulative definition that fits one's purpose/analysis), but I've certainly seen different definitions than the one CGEL chooses.